# Moving swap partition to External USB HD drive

Tags: swap

I have created a swap partition in a USB external Hard Drive. And changed the /etc/fstab file accordingly. The problem is that after reboot, the system hangs and does not start. I am using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling the "USB Legacy support" in the BIOS solved the issue.